# PostgreSQL: Copy Table Functions to another database schema

Tags: postgresql

as the title said. Can we move or copy existing table functions to another database schema?

I can get all the functions from a database schema using command below (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347282/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-functions-stored-in-the-database-of-a-particular-sch)):

`SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type='FUNCTION' AND specific_schema='public';`

And I also can get the function code details using command below (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898453/how-to-display-the-function-procedure-triggers-source-code-in-postgresql)):

`\df+ public.<function_name>`

As I need to move the database to the new server, so I need to copy all table functions inside a specific schema. Say I have a functions called `update()` inside a schema `analytics`.

Can we copy this functions to another database ?
and is there any command to see when this functions will be run?

Note that I am using PostgreSQL 11 and Ubuntu 18.04

[SOLVED]
Sorry for updating this question after 2 years.
The questions has been answered and I'm using the command given by @dezso with slight modification which is:
`pg_dump -Fc --username=dbuser --port=5432 --encoding=utf-8 --clean --no-owner -w -d dbname -f dbname.dump`

as for calling the functions, it is as @a_horse_with_no_name suggest, I'm calling it using cron.

Thank you guys. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell `pg_dump` to dump functions only.  You can exclude tables, but you still have to deal with other objects (like [a_horse_with_no_name said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228525/6219)).

However, you can make a dump without data (`-s`) and filter it upon restoring.  Note the `-Fc` part: this will produce a file suitable for `pg_restore`, which is able to consume a custom-made table of contents.

First take the dump:

```
pg_dump -U username -Fc -s -n public -f dump_test your_database
```

Then create a list of the functions:

```
pg_restore -l dump_test | grep FUNCTION > function_list
```

And finally restore them (`-L` specifies the list file created above):

```
pg_restore -U username -d your_other_database -L function_list dump_test
```

Note that this is a nearly verbatim copy of [my earlier answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758324/246260).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pg_dump` but exclude the data and the table definitions, e.g.:

```
pg_dump -U buzzing_bee -d your_db --schema=public --exclude-table=% --schema-only --file=functions.sql
```

This will however still include the DDL for views, triggers, types or other non-table objects. You will need to edit the generated file and remove those.

Comment: Thanks I am trying using this option : `pg_dump -U postgres -n public -v -Fc -f /tmp/public.dump -d dbname` and I restore using `pg_restore`. After I check, the functions is there. But is there a way to check that these functions will run on my new server??

Comment: @buzzing_bee: well that is an entirely different question. The only way to find out is to create them there and run them.

Comment: I see then. So that the functions is copied (or restored) but that doesn't mean it will run according to schedule?

Comment: what "schedule" are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing. I'm new to postgres. I thought that a functions in a database can be scheduled coz my fellow colleague mentioned that he needs me to make sure this specific function runs every night. Thus, I need to copied the function to new server

Comment: There is no built-in scheduler in Postgres. You need to use e.g. `cron` to run a shell script that runs the function

Comment: Noted, thank you. appreciate the answer and guidance

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758324/246260 for a similar solution, together with how to filter for functions.  And for scheduling, you might want [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)